# Scrape specific NHL score with Python Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape only the total score for a specified team. I have written the following:

```
import urllib.request
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url1 = "http://scores.nbcsports.com/nhl/scoreboard.asp"

## This works, however is using a set day for testing, will need url changed to url1 for current day scoreboard
url = "http://scores.nbcsports.com/nhl/scoreboard.asp?day=20141202"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

allrows = soup.findAll('td')
userows = [t for t in allrows if t.findAll(text=re.compile('Vancouver'))]

print(userows)
```

This returns:

```
[<td><table cellspacing="0"><tr class="shsTableTtlRow"><td class="shsNamD" colspan="1">Final</td>
<td class="shsTotD">1</td>
<td class="shsTotD">2</td>
<td class="shsTotD">3</td>
<td class="shsTotD">Tot</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="shsNamD" nowrap=""><span class="shsLogo"><span class="shsNHLteam22sm_trans"></span></span><a href="/nhl/teamstats.asp?teamno=22&amp;type=stats">Vancouver</a></td>
<td class="shsTotD">1</td>
<td class="shsTotD">2</td>
<td class="shsTotD">1</td>
<td class="shsTotD">4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="shsNamD" nowrap=""><span class="shsLogo"><span class="shsNHLteam23sm_trans"></span></span><a href="/nhl/teamstats.asp?teamno=23&amp;type=stats">Washington</a></td>
<td class="shsTotD">0</td>
<td class="shsTotD">2</td>
<td class="shsTotD">1</td>
<td class="shsTotD">3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>, <td class="shsNamD" nowrap=""><span class="shsLogo"><span class="shsNHLteam22sm_trans"></span></span><a href="/nhl/teamstats.asp?teamno=22&amp;type=stats">Vancouver</a></td>]
```

What I can't seem to get to is the **4** in `<td class="shsTotD">4</td>` from the middle block. If it is only possible to get the **1 2 1 4** I could compare the values and always pick the largest, but I can't even seem to get that far. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the tag containing `Vancouver` and get the next `td` tags by using [`find_next_siblings()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling):

```
vancouver = soup.find('a', text='Vancouver')
for td in vancouver.parent.find_next_siblings('td', class_='shsTotD'):
    print(td.text)
```

Prints:

```
1
2
1
4
```